# regex for path validation

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex to check file path validation and I can't figure out how to exclude "." in a file path without excluding the file extension.

The regex I made is:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]+\.([a-zA-Z]+)$"

/Hello.txt -> should match
/opt/shared/bitnami/im_/age.zip -> should match
this/a/test -> should match
this/another/test/ -> should match
```

EDIT

```
/test/mytest/test_ok.tar.gz -> should match
```

.

```
//test.txt -> should not match
//test -> should not match
/Héllo.txt -> should not match
/opt/shared/bitnami/ /im_/age.zip -> should not match
/opt/shared/bitn.amiim_/age.zip -> should not match
```

Here you can test the regex: https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are matching dots in your regex. I suppose it's for the extension part so i suggest you take that out of your current matching group.

```
^(\/{0,1}(?!\/))[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]+(\.([a-zA-Z]+))?$
```

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/6)

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, it's almost perfect but it doesn't match some valid cases (https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/3). My bad I update the question

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn You could add another optional group, around the extension. `^[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]+(\.([a-zA-Z]+))?$`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/4)

Comment: My bad (again), //this_test.txt and //this_test should not match.
https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/5

Comment: Now this is a little bit more complex. I've added an optional slash at the beginning of the regex with a negative lookahead. This way it check whether or not there is two slash following eachother, at the start of the string. See [Here](https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/6). For the rest, it would be appreciated if you took what we have here and made your part by trying to adapt the regex to your particular needs. @MalkovitchJohn.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you update your answer @Nicolas !

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn Thank you very much !

Comment: Sorry @Nicolas I for a case:

It should be abble to accept: /test/mytest/test_ok.tar.gz

See Here https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/9

Comment: You could change the qualifier of the  `(\.([a-zA-Z]+))` to be `*` rather than `?`. This will tell your regex to check for 0 or multiple extensions. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/10) @MalkovitchJohn

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
^/?[\w-]+(?:/[\w-]+)*(?:\.?([a-zA-Z]+|/))*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/I02pEU/11)

Comment: thanks @Toto for your answer, I just have edited my question, here you cana have the case : regex101.com/r/I02pEU/9

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: Just replace the last `?` with `*`. See my edit.